# Why won't my bound [String] not change my multi-select list SwiftUI

Tags: list, swiftui

I am trying to create a multi-select list:

```
    @Binding var selection:[String]


List {
            ForEach(self.items, id: \.self) { item in
                MultipleSelectionRow(title: item, isSelected: self.selection.contains(item)) {
                    if self.selection.contains(item) {
                        self.selection.removeAll(where: { $0 == item }) <=== NO AFFECT
                    }
                    else {
                        self.selection.append(item). <=== NO AFFECT
                    }
                    self.queryCallback()

                }
            }//ForEach
                .listRowBackground(Color("TPDarkGrey"))
        }//list
```

I have a row which is a button that calls the above action

```
struct MultipleSelectionRow: View {
    var title: String
    var isSelected: Bool
    var action: () -> Void

    var body: some View {

        Button(action: self.action) {
            HStack {
                Text(self.title)
                Spacer()

                if self.isSelected {
                    Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                }
            }
            .font(.system(size: 14))
        }
    }
}
```

Why does it not append or remote the item in the bound array? It seems to change on the second time through the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to produce an example from your code that works:

I don't know how the rest of your code is setup so I cannot hint you to anything unfortunately.

```
struct MultipleSelectionRow: View {
    var title: String
    var isSelected: Bool
    var action: () -> Void

    var body: some View {

        Button(action: self.action) {
            HStack {
                Text(self.title)
                Spacer()

                if self.isSelected {
                    Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                }
            }
            .font(.system(size: 14))
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selection:[String] = []
    @State var items:[String] = ["Hello", "my", "friend", "did", "I", "solve", "your", "question", "?"]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(self.items, id: \.self) { item in
                MultipleSelectionRow(title: item, isSelected: self.selection.contains(item)) {
                    if self.selection.contains(item) {
                        self.selection.removeAll(where: { $0 == item })
                    }
                    else {
                        self.selection.append(item)
                    }

                }
            }
            .listRowBackground(Color("TPDarkGrey"))
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps to clarify things.